# Erro do compilador ou erro de código?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Me deparei com o seguinte caso e não sei se é erro do .NET ou erro na minha implementação, de sintaxe mesmo (ver imagem abaixo).

[image: Visual Studio]

```
condenacaoInsert.qtd_ano_pena = null;
condenacaoInsert.qtd_ano_pena = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(readerCondenacao["qtd_ano_pena"].ToString())) ? int.Parse(readerCondenacao["qtd_ano_pena"].ToString()) : null;
condenacaoInsert.qtd_mes_pena = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(readerCondenacao["qtd_mes_pena"].ToString())) ? int.Parse(readerCondenacao["qtd_ano_pena"].ToString()) : null;
condenacaoInsert.qtd_dia_pena = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(readerCondenacao["qtd_dia_pena"].ToString())) ? int.Parse(readerCondenacao["qtd_ano_pena"].ToString()) : null;
```

Mensagem de erro:

> Error  1   Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and ''(...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É extremamente raro você encontrar um erro no compilador. Nunca considere isto até ter um motivo muito forte. Quantas vezes já achou um erro real do compilador. Em dezenas de linguagens que eu programei em mais de 30 anos, algumas com compiladores não muito bons, eu achei pouco mais de 2 ou 3 erros do compilador e nada grave. E olhe que linguagens de programação é o assunto que mais gosto na computação. Claro que não estou contando com erros que eu achei nos meus compiladores :)

Neste caso você está retornando ou um inteiro (primeiro resultado da condição) ou um nulo. Isto está bem explícito no código.

Não é possível uma variável ser inteiro ou nulo. `qtd_ano_pena` deve ser do tipo `int`. O tipo `int` não aceita valores nulos. Ou você tem que garantir que o resultado dê um inteiro, um zero, por exemplo, se for um valor adequado, ou então terá que mudar o tipo desta variável. Pode mudar para um [`int?`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) que é um tipo inteiro que aceita nulos. o nome dele é inteiro anulável. Claro que seria bom entender todo seu funcionamento porque você pode ter outros problemas em outros lugares se usar ele.

Depois do comentário abaixo do autor percebi que falta um *cast* explícito na primeira expressão, já que ela resulta em inteiro e você quer um inteiro anulável, então ants da expressão deve colocar um `(int?)`. Então poderia fazer tanto:

```
condenacaoInsert.qtd_ano_pena = 
     (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(readerCondenacao["qtd_ano_pena"].ToString())) ?
     (int?)int.Parse(readerCondenacao["qtd_ano_pena"].ToString()) : null;
```

quanto

```
condenacaoInsert.qtd_ano_pena = 
     (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(readerCondenacao["qtd_ano_pena"].ToString())) ? 
     int.Parse(readerCondenacao["qtd_ano_pena"].ToString()) : (int?)null;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/CastNullable.cs).

Comment: Prezado, perdoe minha omissão, neste caso "condenacaoInsert.qtd_ano_pena" já é do tipo "int?", asim como os demais "qtds". Observe que na linha acima, coloquei como exemplo "condenacaoInsert.qtd_ano_pena = null", demonstrando que é possível a aceitação de nulo para o mesmo campo.

Comment: @SantanaFire editei p/ resolver, eu colocaria toda a linha se você tivesse postado o código e o erro. Prefira postar o em texto o código e o erro, fica mais fácil para gente ler e manipular. A *screenshot* pode ser auxiliar mas não no ligar do texto. Ainda dá para fazer isto, edite lá.

Comment: Prezado bigown!!! Perfeito, a solução era incluir o cast explicito! Obrigado.